# Where can I study cognitive science - long distance program?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

Just recently discovered the field of cognitive science. The more i read, the more I discover how complex this is. I would love to study this and be able to find out that specific segment for me and then develop it. In Romania (where I live) this is not a developped domain. I would like to study abroad but I could not afford moving for 1 year in another country. In case you can recomment short term workshops in Europe i would very much appreciate it.

Comment: I would hesitate to say that no one in an entire country is studying the subject.  Cognitive Science is not always studied in departments labeled as "Cognitive Science."  It tends to span multiple academic disciplines, and therefore, could be a concentration that is available to you through a psychology, neuroscience, computer science, etc., program.

Comment: Agreed with Chuck; it looks like at least both the University of Bucharest and Babeș-Bolyai have cognitive science programs. Here's one lab, for example: http://www.cognitive-neuroscience.ro they are housed in the Department of Psychology. I just searched Google for "cognitive science Romania" and found lots of results, yet I'm a bit limited by only speaking English.

Answer (score 2):

There are a huge array of options here depending on the sophistication of the course you are looking for.

I would suggest for a free option starting with MIT, they provide a large range of modules online associated with psychology and neuroscience (please see the attached link) with videos of the lectures they have conducted within the university. A wonderful starting point in my opinion.

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/brain-and-cognitive-sciences/

The british geoscience association also list a number of online courses [here](https://www.bna.org.uk/careers/online-courses-moocs/), however these are often more biologically focused than cognitive in nature. Most the short courses are less than £70.

There is also a range of courses on coursera provided by various universities, which will provide you with accreditation for the courses, [here is a list](https://neurosciencenews.com/free-neuroscience-moocs/).

As for workshops, they tend to be relatively expensive as most are provided for post-grads, many of which are working with individuals conducting neuroimaging studies as part of MSc or PhD projects and beyond. These are only really helpful when you start conducting studies. You can find many courses [listed here](https://www.bna.org.uk/mediacentre/events/) on the British Neuroscience Associations website (the courses are based across many European countries).

I hope you enjoy your journey into what I believe is the most exciting area of scientific investigation. I would add one piece of advice, make sure you develop a good back ground in research methods and statistics (both are equally important) as this is what helps you to understand if research is good or bad, along with developing your own research skills for the future. Here is a basic but free [starting point](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/child-health/short-courses-events/about-statistical-courses/introduction-research-methods-and-statistics), I would recommend something with more advance statistical methods for going further.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to reply. Very helpful, i can not wait to dive into it.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer from @Comte, there are also [Open University courses in Psychology](http://www.open.ac.uk/courses/find/psychology-and-counselling) here in the UK